# JAVA - Using Box.createGlue() to position objects at the bottom of the Screen?

Tags: java, swing

I searched and found no answer anywhere on the internet I could find so here I am.

JFrame with Background

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9ymV.png]

This is what I have currently, the logo that says "The Pentecostals of Katy, Texas" is what I'm working on, as well as the copyright symbol.

I want the logo to be on the bottom and the copyright to be on the bottom right. Here is all of the code that builds the Frame:

```
//Made by Trey Carey | 6.24.18

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class loginScreen {
    static String versionNumber = new String("1.0"); //Version Number
    static String applicationName = new String("Lower Thirds SDV " + versionNumber); //Application Name

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        createLoginWindow();
    }


    public static void createLoginWindow() throws IOException {     
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame(applicationName);

        //Images
        BufferedImage loginImage = ImageIO.read(new File ("src/Lower Thirds SDV PNG Elements/Login_BTN.png"));
        JLabel backgroundImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/Lower Thirds SDV PNG Elements/Main_BKG.png"));
        JLabel logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/Lower Thirds SDV PNG Elements/POK Logo.png"));
        JLabel copyrightImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/Lower Thirds SDV PNG Elements/Copyright.png"));

        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        mainFrame.add(backgroundImage);
        backgroundImage.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
        //Create Login Button
        JButton loginButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon (loginImage));
        loginButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.gridy = 0;
        backgroundImage.add(loginButton, c);
        c.gridy ++;
        backgroundImage.add(copyrightImage, c);
        backgroundImage.add(Box.createGlue(), c);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        c.gridy ++;
        backgroundImage.add(logo, c);


        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `I searched and found no answer anywhere on the internet` - I find that hard to believe. All you need to do is search the forum/web using "Box.createGlue()" as a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using Box.createGlue() to position objects at the bottom of the Screen?

Then you need to use the `BoxLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for examples to get you started.

The reason your components are in the middle is because you are using the GridBagLayout and unless you specify a weightx/y the components will be centered. Read the tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information about those constraints.

Note, you are never forced to use a single layout manager. So maybe the main panel uses a BoxLayout. Then you create two other panels each using an appropriate layout manager. Then you can use the Box.createGlue() to separate the bottom panel from the top panel.

Comment: I read somewhere (Can't find source at the moment I'm at work) that I could use this createGlue() in GridBagLayout also. If it's not possible how can I add a blank space there?

Comment: `If it's not possible how can I add a blank space there?` - use nested panels as I suggested above.